"The myriad" or "a myriad"?
I'm describing an experience helping a group gain access to a certain sport. Right now, the sentence reads

The students were from schools that faced the myriad of barriers restricting access to the sport.

Is this grammatically correct? Would "a myriad" or "the myriad barriers" be more correct?

Are these barriers a specific set of barriers, or just a large number of barriers that might not directly relate to the factors under discussion?

There's no grammatical rule that says you can't use the myriad of; see Ngrams.

What's the point of having an article here in the first place?  And was it the students or the schools facing said barriers? These students came from schools that had put up myriad barriers restricting the students’ access to the sport.

"Myriad" literally means "ten thousand", and all of the examples I've seen of its recommended grammatical usage imply that you should use it without any article, either "a" or "the", in contexts where you could substitute "ten thousand" for it and have the sentence still be grammatical.

@DougWarren Yes, it's been rather watered down through overuse of late. It's a fancy-looking Greek word that's been overused so much that now you can never tell any longer whether someone means several or various or many or numerous or countless or numberless or unnumbered or innumerable. Most sentences using it would be better served by one of those instead.

'... the myriad barriers' or '... the myriads of barriers' (compare the cases with 'hundred' though 'the myriad' sounds better than 'the hundred', interpreted as estimates. Also compare 'the dozen' and 'the dozens of', though again the former is rather unusual for a rough figure.
